# How do I convert "curl -k https://www.example.com" in php curl code?

Tags: php-curl

The following code executes without an errors.But, My website is breaking down and it responses the same data for all the pages on website.

```
        $URL = 'https://www.example.com';
            $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    // Do not check the SSL certificates
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    // Return the actual result of the curl result instead of success code
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    // Fetch the URL and save the content in $html variable
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $res;
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking.  `My website is breaking down` - what does this mean?  Please edit your question and clarify, show us any errors you are getting, etc.  One note - you are doing `curl_exec()` twice - that means you are making the request 2x.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem, your curl script is working but breaking the PHP of your website ? 
If yes, can you provide more informations ? In which file did you put that code ? The files that are broken, ...

Moreover, you can use `curl_setopt_array` if you want to set more than 1 option. It will be more readable.

Ex :

```php
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    ));
```